# swift - cannot make my if statement work is well as i need

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, url

i have a problem when i typed my code as is bellow but i got error ?!

i want user if typed code = 4234 on textFields and tap on "ADD" = "https://pastebin.com/raw/4234"

else = any url "http://www.example.com/"

```
@IBAction func btnPlusPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Provider M3U URL", message: "Add Provided URL to add you M3U Plailist", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ADD", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        var url = alert.textFields![0]

        if (url.text == "535" as String ){
            let strURLl : String = "https://pastebin.com/raw/\(url.text!)"

        }else{
            let strURLl : String = "\(url.text!)"
        }


        UserDefaults .standard .set(strURLl, forKey: "URL")

        let channelsVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChannelsViewController") as! ChannelsViewController
        channelsVC.strURL = strURLl!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(channelsVC, animated: true)

    })
```

why error appear like this : (Use of unresolved identifier 'strURLl')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are defining the constant `strURLl` within the scope of the IF statement.
It means you cannot use it once outside of those `{` `}` around it

```
if (url.text == "535" as String ){
    let strURLl : String = "https://pastebin.com/raw/\(url.text!)"
} else {
    let strURLl : String = "\(url.text!)"
}
```

> Same problem with the else statement.

### Solution

Simply declare the constant outside of the IF scope

```
let strURLl: String
if (url.text == "535" as String ){
    strURLl = "https://pastebin.com/raw/\(url.text!)"
} else {
    strURLl = "\(url.text!)"
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `as String` ? And why isn't the `else` simply `strURLl = url.text!`

Comment: @rmaddy There's no point indeed. I only made the single change related to the issue in order to make the explanation cleared. But yours is a good point.

Comment: Considering that the OP doesn't understand Swift very well, it would be best if the answer fixed all of the issues with their code.

Comment: @rmaddy your opinion is well, but i think it for sure type "string" not "Integer" on textField.

Comment: @user3650740 That is incorrect. Both `url.text` and the literal `"535"` are of type `String`. The literal `535` (no quotes) is of type `Int`.

Comment: @rmaddy anyway, thank you, i changed to (strURLl = url.text!) its worked well too .

Comment: That's wrong too. It needs to be `==`, not `=`. `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment. And you don't need the `( )` in a Swift `if` statement. Please take time to read the [Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html).

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for all tips,  i'm new in iOS development i wasn't note it.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti can i make edit (url.text == "535" as String ) to changeable value for user like 75 or 84.. etc?!